# processing inputs from user

Tags: python, if-statement, asynchronous, async-await

I have a discord on_command function that takes an input from the user and asks a questions

```
async def on_command(command: str):
      if self.state == 'start':
          if command == '/question'
            self.send_command('Whats the capital of NY?')
            self.state = 'waiting_answer'
```

The problem I'm having is if 2 people almost at the same time type the /question command it will ask the question 2 times instead of once. I want it to just process the first question asked. How do I ensure this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. In this example, there isn't any way to tell what is what. Also edit the tags accordingly with pycord or discord.py depending on which you use. That being said try setting self.state to "waiting_answer" right after `if command == "/question":`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check before the question is asked to make sure that just the first question is handled and that any more questions are disregarded. Here is a revised version of your on_command function that includes the required change:

```py
async def on_command(command: str):
    if self.state == 'start':
        if command == '/question':
            if self.state != 'waiting_answer':
                self.send_command('What is the capital of NY?')
                self.state = 'waiting_answer'
```

I am not 100% sure if it works, so please tell me if it worked for you.